# Why is "berauben" used with genitive noun?

Tags: verb, genitive

The verb [berauben](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/berauben) is used with a genitive noun in the format

> jemanden einer Sache berauben

Is there any reason why genitive? The related verb [rauben](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/rauben) is used with a dative, as is more common with other verbs.

(I'm actually happy enough to just memorize that it's used with a genitive, but it would be nice to know the background/reason behind that.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot provide an etymological reason for the cases the verb *berauben* rules. However, I have the feeling that the main cause lies in the prefix *be-*. Let's analyze the cases of *berauben* and *rauben*:

> jemandem (Dat.) etwas (Akk.) rauben
>
> jemanden (Akk.) einer Sache (Gen.) berauben

We can see that the prefix *be-* shifted the accusative case from the stolen goods to the person who is robbed. As we [can read on canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/Praefixe/be.html), this shift is one of the functions of the prefix *be-*. Canoo mentions another example:

> jemandem (Dat.) etwas (Akk.) schenken
>
> jemanden (Akk.) [mit etwas] beschenken.

As a rule of thumb, one can say that if a verb needs two nouns, the "thing"-y object (direct object) is in accusative case and the "person"-y object (indirect object) is in dative case, e.g.:

> jemandem (Dat.) etwas (Akk.) geben/sagen/erzählen/schenken/rauben...

Now if the *be-* prefix shifts the "person"-y object to accusative case, the slot of the "thing"-y object has to be filled again with a different case.
I guess the dative case is not considered for this re-filling of the slot because that would result in a swap of cases (which somehow would be confusing).
The accusative case would result in a double accusative (which is not unheard of but maybe not preferred intuitively by the speakers).

So one has to find a different method to re-fill the "thing"-y slot. There aren't so many possibilities left: *Preposition + noun* or *noun in genitive case*:
In the case of *beschenken* the "thing"-y slot is refilled by a preposition (*mit*) + noun. In the case of *berauben* the "thing"-y slot is refilled by a genitive noun.

Answer (score 1):

The genitive is only used for the object that's robbed of somebody:

> Der Räuber (nom.) hat den Mann (acc.) seiner Brieftasche (gen.) beraubt

Also note that this is high register and a very formal way of putting it. It's actually much more common to use the passive here:

> Dem Mann (dat.) wurde die Brieftasche (nom.) geraubt

(Also, it's common not to differentiate between robbery and theft in everyday speech.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the verb construction jemand einer Sache berauben is influenced by Latin or modelled after Latin.

The Latin grammar has a chapter about ablative of separation where the construction of verbs such as orbare, privare, spoliare, exuere, all of them meaning berauben, plus ablative is explained.

Egere/ indigere could have ablative or genitive. As German has no ablative, I think, the genitive was adopted.

Another consideration: If you have a verb as berauben with an accusative (for the person who is robbed) and have to add a second object (for the thing that is robbed) there is only a genitive possible as a dative would make no sense.

Comment: In German, the ablative has merged with the dative, which is why "aus", "von" etc. all take the dative. So I don't think this is the reason why "berauben" takes the genitive.

Comment: Well, the Latin clue isn't bad, but it is not the ablative - It rather is a direct construct known as *genitivus criminis* in Latin that (might have) ended up in German.